# Apache spark code issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**Code not running**

scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext.
| import org.apache.spark.
<console>:2: error: identifier expected but 'import' found.
import org.apache.spark.
^

scala> object SparkWordCount {
 |    def main(args: Array[String]) {
 |     val sc = new SparkContext( "local", "Word Count", "/usr/local/spark", Nil, Map(), Map())
 |       val input = sc.textFile("C:\\x.txt")
 |       Val count = input.flatMap(line ? line.split(" "))
 |       .map(word ? (word, 1))
 |       .reduceByKey(_ + _)
 |       count.saveAsTextFile("C:\\x1.txt")
 |       System.out.println("OK");
 |    }
 | }
```

**After Enter i am getting :**

```
<console>:48: error: overloaded method constructor SparkContext with alternative
s:  (master: String,appName: String,sparkHome: String,jars: Seq[String],environment:scala.collection.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.    SparkContext <and> (master: String,appName:    String,conf:org.apache.spark.SparkConf)org.apache.spark.SparkContext <and> ()org.apache.spark.SparkContext <and>
  (config: org.apache.spark.SparkConf)org.apache.spark.SparkContext
 cannot be applied to (String, String, String, scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type, scala.collection.immutable.Map[Nothing,Nothing], scala.collection.immutable.Map[Nothing,Nothing])
       val sc = new SparkContext( "local", "Word Count", "/usr/local/spark",Nil, Map(), Map())




<console>:50: error: not found: value Val
         Val count = input.flatMap(line ? line.split(" "))
         ^
<console>:53: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,both method count in object functions of type (columnName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[Any,Long] and  method count in object functions of type (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column match expected type ? count.saveAsTextFile("C:\\x1.txt")
```

**Also when i am trying to import a text file ,it is not taking place**

```
scala> val file = sc.textFile("c:\\x.txt")
<console>:46: error: not found: value sc
   val file = sc.textFile("c:\\x.txt")
              ^
```

**When i am tryng with single"/" then i am getting error invalid escape character ,when i trying with "//" then showing nothing**

```
scala> val file = sc.textFile("c:\x.txt")
<console>:1: error: invalid escape character
val file = sc.textFile("c:\x.txt")
                       ^

scala>
```

Do help me, i am not understanding why this is happening?i have installed spark on windows

Comment: You are using spark-shell ? There is so many things wrong with your code actually.

Comment: Its not the spark shell, it’s the Scala console he is using . try the code in a spark shell first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a lot buggy. Try the following code

```
import org.apache.spark._
object SparkWordCount {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val conf = new SparkConf()
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf.setMaster("local").setAppName("Word Count")))
      val input = sc.textFile("C:\\x.txt")
      val count = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
       .map(word => (word, 1))
       .reduceByKey(_ + _)
      count.saveAsTextFile("C:\\x1.txt")
      System.out.println("OK");
    }
}
```

I hope it works